# How does jQuery's .delay method work under-the-hood?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just saw this and think it's cool.

```
console.log("Starting...");
$("#my_element")
  .fadeIn()
  .delay(3000)
  .fadeOut();
console.log("Finishing...");
```

How does the .delay method work under-the-hood?  I mean, how does it figure out how to wait 3 seconds but not interrupt the main control flow?

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=delay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery has an internal "queue" object, that is just an array:

```
[ nextAction,
  action,
  action,
  lastAction ]
```

When you use `delay`, it pushes:

```
function delay( ms ){
   setTimeout( dequeue, ms )
}
```

Meaning that once it gets to the delay, there's a timeout and then the next action is fired.  Actions that happen immediately, like `.css`, however, do:

```
function css(){
    // do stuff
    dequeue();
}
```

no delay.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically using timeouts with your time that you put into the delay function.

See the source code here: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=delay

The code for queue and dequeue are also useful:
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=queue
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.dequeue