# Creating a method similar to delay in my own class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a method similar to delay() from JQuery.
I am creating a method called $. Remember **I am not using JQuery** and don't want to for this problem.

```
function $(element) {
  if(!(this instanceof $)) {
    return new $(element);
  }
  this.element = document.querySelector(element);
}

$.prototype.color = function color(color) {
  this.element.style.color = color;
}
```

I can use this method like so:

```
$('#foo').color('red);
```

It will change the color of #foo to red

What I am trying to do is set a delay before it changes the color. One way would be to do :

```
$.prototype.delay(time, fn) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fn();
  }, time);
}
```

and then call it like so:

```
$('#foo').delay(1000, function() {
  $('#foo').color('red');
});
```

But that's not very useful, what I would like to do instead is use it like so:

```
$('#foo').delay(1000).color('red);
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617240/how-does-jquerys-delay-method-work-under-the-hood) but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance,
I.L

**One way of doing it (@georg)**

```js
// create a new instance if it doesn't already exists when $ is called
function $(element) {
  if(!(this instanceof $)) {
    return new $(element);
  }
  this.element = document.querySelector(element);
  this.promise = Promise.resolve(this);
  this.css = this.element.style;
}

// wrapper for the promise
$.prototype.method = function(name, fn) {
  $.prototype[name] = function(...args) {
    this.promise.then(self => fn.apply(self, args));
    return this;
  };
}

// delay method, 
$.prototype.delay = function(time) {
  this.promise = new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(this), time));
  return this;
}

// example of a method to change the color
$.prototype.method('color', function (color) {
  this.css.color = color;
});

// used like so
$('#foo').delay(2000).color('green');
```

```html
<div id="foo">Hi there!</div>
```

**I have found another nice solution that allows to use delay multiple time see my answer for more details.**

Comment: You could try hooking into promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using chainable methods and setting a delay method:

```js
function $(element) {
  if(!(this instanceof $)) {
    return new $(element);
  }

  // select all elements with this identifier
  this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(element);

  // by default select the first element of querySelectorAll
  this.element = this.elements[0];
  this.css = this.element.style;

  // first method applied will be exectuted directly
  this.delayTime = 0;
}


$.prototype.$ = function position(pos) {

  if(pos == 'first') {
    pos = 0;
  } else if(pos == 'last') {
    pos = this.elements.length-1;
  }

  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    that.element = that.elements[pos] || that.elements[0];
    that.css = that.element.style;
  }, this.delayTime);

  return this;
}

$.prototype.delay = function(delayTime) {
  // set a delay for the following method applied
  this.delayTime += delayTime;

  return this;
}

// wraps the method into a setTimeout
$.prototype.method = function(name, fn) {
  $.prototype[name] = function(...args) {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      // method will only take one relevant parameter
      fn(that, args[0]);
    }, this.delayTime);
    return this;
  };
}

// CSS methods
$.prototype.method('backgroundColor', function(self, color) {
  self.css.backgroundColor = color;
})

$('#foo').delay(1000).backgroundColor('blue').delay(1000).backgroundColor('white').delay(1000).backgroundColor('red');
```

```css
#foo {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Hey there!</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with promises. Requires some more work to be practical, but should give you an idea. Basically, all methods like `color` should operate on "resolved this" instead of just "this":

```js
function $(element) {
  if(!(this instanceof $)) {
    return new $(element);
  }
  this.element = document.querySelector(element);
  this.promise = Promise.resolve(this)
}

$.prototype.color = function color(color) {
  this.promise.then(function(self) {
    self.element.style.color = color;
  });
}

$.prototype.delay = function(n) {
  this.promise = new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(this), n));
  return this;
}

$('#foo').color('red');
$('#foo').delay(1000).color('blue');
```

```html
<div id="foo">foo</div>
```

For automated promisifying you can use a wrapper like this:

```
$.prototype.method = function(name, fn) {
  $.prototype[name] = function(...args) {
    this.promise.then(self => fn.apply(self, args));
    return this;
  };
}
```

and then, for example,

```
$.prototype.method('color', function (color) {
  this.element.style.color = color;
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Is there a way to avoid writing `this.promise.then(function() {})` in each method ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how jQuery implement it :

```
    function (time, type) {
        time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[time] || time : time;
        type = type || "fx";

        return this.queue(type, function () {
            var elem = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery.dequeue(elem, type);
            },
            time);
        });
    }
```

Using only* Queue :

```
    function (type, data) {
        if (typeof type !== "string") {
            data = type;
            type = "fx";
        }

        if (data === undefined) {
            return jQuery.queue(this[0], type);
        }
        return this.each(function () {
            var queue = jQuery.queue(this, type, data);

            if (type === "fx" && queue[0] !== "inprogress") {
                jQuery.dequeue(this, type);
            }
        });
    }
```

And Dequeue :

```
function (type) {
    return this.each(function () {
        jQuery.dequeue(this, type);
    });
}
```

- The only external jQuery call in these functions is "jQuery.fx", with can be avoided.

From there, it will be easy to implement these 3 functions in your own model.

Comment: Do you know how to use them?